Conflict with "p" tabular col-spec in aastex631 template documentclass?
I was using the aastex6.3.1 template here, and the example file sample631.tex couldn't compiled with latexmk -pdflatex on TL2024 on windows11 with the following message:
Package natbib Warning: Citation `2016AJ....152...41P' on page 18 undefined on
input line 1365.

! Extra \or.
<argument> ...pach \ifcase \@chclass \@classz \or
                                                  \@classi \or \@classii \or...
l.1388 ...ght 14pt depth 6pt width 0pt}llllp{3in}}

It seems that the problem raised in Line 1356 by \citet{2016AJ....152...41P}., and what's more, there remain anothor problem with the p{3in}  in tabular with aastex6.3.1 template in Line 1387 of sample631.tex.(Here below is a minimal working example for the latter problem)
% Line 1387 of `sample631.tex`
\begin{tabular}{@{\vrule height 14pt depth 6pt width 0pt}llllp{3in}}
1.&\verb+\nom{(GM)}+& \nom{(GM)} &=& nominal solar mass parameter\\
2.&\verb+\nom{R}+&\nom{R} &=& nominal solar radius\\
3.&\verb+\nom{S}+& \nom{S}&=&  nominal total solar irradiance\\
4.&\verb+\nom{L}+& \nom{L}  &=&nominal solar luminosity\\
\end{tabular}

\documentclass[linenumbers]{aastex631}
% \documentclass{article} % work with article but failed with aastex631
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llllp{3in}}
  1111 & 2222 & 3333 & 4444 & 5555 \\
  1111 & 2222 & 3333 & 4444 & 5555 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}

The MWE resulted the following error:
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \interlinepenalty@ltx
l.10 \begin{tabular}{llllp{3in}}

I wonder how to fix the (maybe) bug above to use the template fluently. Thanks!

Perhaps related to https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1585 but I can't test now.

I found it a little strange that that how come such an example .tex file received no issues and doubt about it on TSE.

The class uses revtex4-2 as internal class, and revtex redefines almost all of the latex tabular code, and seems not to be compatible with array anymore. Your small example compiles if I disable most of the patches with \makeatletter \def\switch@array{}\makeatother, but the sample file still breaks.

@UlrikeFischer isn't it even worse, the cls requires revtex4-1 (question about it the other day, miktex does not provide 4-1)

@daleif yes that complicates stuff even more. But as far as I can see the main problem is revtex.

Is that means is the revtex documentclass cause the problem(?) And where I compiled the tex file is on TeXLive2024 but NOT miktex, which confused me a bit. @daleif

revtex4-1 is in texlive.

I have consulted the .cls however I could only search the revtex4-1, is there typo in your previous comment mentioning revtex4-2.  And actually the texlive have both revtex4-1 and revtex4-2.And after my test, both of two revtex document class version handle the p col-spec correctly, it seems the problem should be blamed for the additional settings of aastex631?@UlrikeFischer

it breaks if the array package is loaded.

However, the array package is dependency with other command like \newcolumntype, what's the Best Practice in this example case?

The best practice is to report the bugs. In revtex4-2 a tabular like \begin{tabular}{p{3in}} errors if array is loaded. So report that to the revtex and asstex631 maintainer.

@UlrikeFischer Okay, thanks yr advice, I will keep up the progress here.

I found the relate issue here: https://github.com/AASJournals/AASTeX60/issues/149. It seemed we can only rool back the array.sty to a older version.
